# Run a VirtualBox Virtual Machine from an Ubuntu Server shell?

Tags: ubuntu, command-line, virtualbox, virtual-machine, gui

I have a server running Ubuntu Server 19.10 with no GUI and no screen attached. I only connect to it through SSH.

Is it possible to install VirtualBox on there and run a Virtual Machine that does have its own (virtual) screen, even though the screen isn't displayed or outputted anywhere by the host machine?

For example I want to run a Windows 10 Virtual Machine. I want to launch it from the shell, and I will then interact with it using VirtualBox's CLI/API functionality to send keyboard & mouse commands, grab screenshots, etc.

Obviously the Windows instance in the Virtual Machine will need to think it has a screen, whereas in reality it's running in a command-line-only host environment where the screen cannot be shown.

If necessary I could first create and setup the VM elsewhere, on an Ubuntu Desktop PC where I do have a GUI so I can interact visually. But once I have a fully installed and working VM, I'd want to copy the files to the Ubuntu Server and run it from there.

Is this possible, and if yes, how?

FYI the reason I want this is for various automation tasks and scripted testing processes.

Comment: I am totally impressed your running a server without a screen. I probably would not even be able to type this comment without looking at it. Cool Name! I am giving you 1Up just for being able to function without a screen!

Comment: @vssher In fact, there isn't even a keyboard and mouse attached to the server either! How about that!

Comment: The short answer is yes and absolutely.  Start by reading [Chapter 8 of the VirtualBox Documentation](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch08.html) - VBoxManage.  You can do everything via the command line including installing and using a GUI OS like Windows.  Hint:  VRDP